# Where can I find a tutorial how to build a SAIL for sesame2 store?

Tags: java, semantics, hsqldb, sesame

I would like to implement a [SAIL](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch05.html) (for [sesame2](http://www.openrdf.org/)) that lets me to store triples in [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/). I have found basic documentation on the sesame website about: [Sail API](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch05.html), [Sail Query API](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch06.html), [Repository API](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch07.html), but I can not find any tutorial (which explaining API based on an example) which would help me to start. Does anybody have experience with the sail development? Could anybody point me to some materials on the web that would help me in my development?

Comment: Try asking on http://www.semanticoverflow.com as I know some of the Sesame developers check that website plus your question is more likely to be seen by a Semantic Web expert on there

Comment: See the [crossposted question on semantic overflow](http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/3064/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-how-to-build-a-sail-for-sesame2-store) for further discussion.